# cqlsh DESCRIBE TABLE foo returns only "u'type'"

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have a keyspace `foo` and a simple table `bar` with a few columns.

When I run:

```
cqlsh DESCRIBE TABLE foo.bar;
```

cqlsh simply returns:

```
u'type'
```

My understanding is that cqlsh should output a list of CQL commands that could be used to recreate the given keyspace, and the tables in it.

I am using:

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 1.2.18 | CQL spec 3.0.1 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your syntax is correct. What do you see if you run `SELECT * FROM foo.bar;`

Comment: Exactly what I would expect, a view of the table and everything in it.

Comment: is the problem with all tables, or just this one? Also, have you tried side-loading another C* version to see if the issue repeats?

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you fix this finally? When I type desc [table], cql returns u'type' for all tables.